# HELP Recover ETH from my own smart contract

Tags: scam, recover

I created a contract I found on the web,  on ETH to play with slipage. I am trying to recover the ETH in the contract. ETH was sent from Metamask.

this is the contract adress: 0x65418434c9D588547168203fE86F66975C2B992f

Can anybody help please ? really sucks. will pay for any support. thanks

Comment: Hello Sarpi! Without observing the contract's code, no one could help you out! Please consider adding your contract's code here

Comment: Thanks, sure here is the code... https://pastebin.com/raw/Bnvn7qag

Comment: Unfortunately it is a well known scam contract that has been circulating for several years. The contract has a backdoor that allows the scammer to retrieve the funds with an "internal transaction".

Comment: THe thing is that the eth is still in contract. I checked  on Ethscan, still there.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you installed one of those contracts that gives all your money to a scammer.

It's gone. You donated it to a scammer. You can't get it back.

There are only 3 things you can do with this contract besides send it money: `receive` (which does nothing), `withdrawal` (which sends all the money to the scammer) and `start` (which sends all the money to the scammer)

You found some token recovery code on the internet, that you can put in your contract to let you recover tokens, but you did not put that code in your contract so you can't use it to recover tokens, and ethers aren't a token anyway.

Comment: But the ETH is still on the contract. nobody took it. Isn't there any way to withdraw from REMIX or else ?

Comment: @Sarpi you can call the start or withdrawProfits functions which will transfer it to the scammer (not you)!

Comment: I read that it could be done with Ethscan, but I can t find the contracts actions they describe

Comment: @Sarpi your contract has only three actions: receive (which doesn't do anything), start (which sends the money to the scammer) and withdrawal (not withdrawProfits, my mistake) (which sends the money to the scammer)

Comment: I know what I did was stupid. no question on that.

Comment: @Sarpi Bargaining with me won't change the fact your money is gone.

Comment: pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "eth-token-recover/contracts/TokenRecover.sol";

contract MyContract is TokenRecover {
  // your stuff
}

Comment: saw something like that, but Don't know how to use it actually

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-token-recover

Comment: @Sarpi Finding random bits of code on github won't change the fact that your money is gone. Did you write in your contract `contract UniswapFrontrunBot is TokenRecover`? No you did not write that.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time